# Perl: how to parse Date from a string

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write a regular expression that extracts Date from a string.

Here is a string examples:

Date: Tue, 11 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100 (CET)

Date: Tue, 9 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100 (CET)

Here is what I tried:

```
$str =~ /Date.+(\d+\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{4}).+(CET)/;
print $1;
$str =~ /Date.+(\d{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{4}).+(CET)/;
print $1
```

Both fail when I have two digit day. I have tried different variations but unsuccessfully.

I was able to make it work with following:

```
$str =~ /Date.+(\s\d+\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{4}).+(CET)/;
my $date = $1;
$date =~ s/^\s//;
```

Unfortunately, this is not a pretty solution. I am sure there is a way to make it happen in regex I just cannot find it.

Please advise.

Thank you,

-Andrey

Comment: Your three line solution can be written as `my ($date) = $str =~ /Date.+\s(\d+\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{4}).+(CET)/;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `.+` in your regex is greedily matching the first of the two digits in the date, leaving only one for the capturing group.  Just change it to `.+?` to match as few characters as possible.

Incidentally, the `(CET)` at the end of your regex is not matching the string `"(CET)"`, but just `"CET"`, since the unescaped parentheses form a second capturing group.  You probably want to say `\(CET\)`.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

I think you should use [Date::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Parse.pm).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Parse;

my $date = "Tue, 11 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100 (CET)";
my $time = str2time($date);
# or like this
my @arr = strptime($date);
```

If you want to stick to regex, like Sean points out, you must be aware that the first `.+` matches everything up to `CET`, leaving nothing for the capturing parentheses to capture. An alternative to your code could be as simple as this:

```
if ($str =~ /Date: (.*) \(CET\)/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

EDIT:

As @Dave mentioned in the comment, parsing the string using [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.27/Piece.pm#Date_Parsing), which is included in the standard Perl modules, may be a better idea if you want to be specific about the format of the string. In that case,

```
 my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "Date: %a, %d %b %Y %T %z (%Z)");
```

will give you the Time::Piece object.

Comment: I don't think anyone should use Date::Parse :-) Time::Piece is a standard Perl module, and the DateTime family of modules exists for more complex requirements.

Comment: I do understand that Time::Piece objects allow you to have more flexibility, but why do you think Date::Parse is a bad idea?

Comment: I don't like Date::Parse because it's too magical. It takes any number of date/time formats and attempts to parse them all. And having been burnt once too often by people who think that MM/DD/YY is an acceptable format for dates, I'm wary of anything that doesn't want me to closely define the format of the date I'm getting. Time::Piece is already installed and does the job. Why look for anything else?

Comment: Thanks, I see your point now. I updated my answer to reflect that :)

Comment: This is a good solution, but I was trying to find specific regex solution. Sean's answer I like a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For simple matching (i.e. if you don't need to manipulate the date after capturing it), I like [Regexp::Common::time](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Regexp-Common-time-0.01/time.pm):

```
use Regexp::Common qw(time);

my $format = '%a, %_d %b %Y %T %Z';

while (<DATA>) {
    say $1 if /($RE{time}{strftime}{-pat => $format})/;
}

__DATA__
Date: Tue, 11 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100 (CET)
Date: Tue, 9 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100 (CET)
```

#### Output:

```
Tue, 11 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100
Tue, 9 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100
```

Note that Regexp::Common::time supports *most*, but not all, of the formatting codes from POSIX `strftime`. In the example above, I had to use `%Z` instead of `%z` as well as the nonstandard `%_d`.

Answer (score 2):

Provided the input is always in the format you present, this should work:

```
my $string = 'Date: Tue, 11 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100 (CET)';

my ($day, $month, $year) = $string =~ /Date:.+?(\d+)\s(.+?)\s(\d+)/;

print "$day\t$month\t$year\n";
```

Prints:

```
11  Feb 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece) has been included with the standard Perl distribution since 5.10 in 2007. it has a `strptime` method that makes this simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $fmt = 'Date: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)';

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($_, $fmt);
  # use $dt->strftime(...) for more control of output
  say $dt->datetime;
}

__DATA__
Date: Tue, 11 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100 (CET)
Date: Tue, 9 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100 (CET)
```

Comment: On my machine I get `Error parsing time at /usr/lib64/perl5/Time/Piece.pm line 470, <DATA> line 1.` Looks like the issue is with `(CET)`, which you could probably ignore since the time zone offset is already specified.

Comment: Interesting. Which version of Time::Piece are you using? I have 1.20_01 which works fine on both Ubuntu and Centos. It looks like the actual [strptime implementation](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/Time-Piece-1.27/Piece.xs) is in XS, so it's possible that it depends on the underlying C libraries.

Comment: I *was* on 1.15. Upgrading to 1.27 fixed the issue.

Comment: Looks like that was fixed in [version 1.16](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Time-Piece#L54).

Answer (score 1):

You could just be really specific:

```
\s((?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun),\s\d+\s(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s\+\d+\s\(\w+\))
```

[See it work](http://regex101.com/r/qV3dE4)

Answer (score 1):

#### My personal date parser

I use this a lot in small log parsers...

At begin of your script, create two variables: `%month` and `$mntregex`:

```
use POSIX qw|strftime setlocale LC_TIME|;
setlocale( LC_TIME, "C" );

my %month;
map {$month{strftime("%b",1,1,1,1,$_,1,-1,-1,-1)}=$_;} (0..13);
my $mntregex = join( "|", keys %month );
```

Well then now you could grep and parse date simply:

```
# Format ref: Date: Tue, 11 Feb 2014 11:01:57 +0100 (CET)

/^Date:\s+\S+,\s+(\d+)\s+($mntregex)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s/ && do {
    $tstamp=strftime("%s",$6,$5,$4,$3,$month{$2},$1-1900,-1,-1,-1);
     ...
```

This don't depend on libraries and is someting quicker than

#### The other way

But without proper check:

```
use Date::Parse;

$tstamp=str2time($1) if /^Date: (.*)$/;
```